# How to monitor progress of md5 hashing of large drives/many files?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking for the simplest and least intrusive way to monitor the progress of md5 fingerprinting of large drives, many files (8 TB, 2 million).

What would be the best option, for example in case it gets stuck or begins an infinite loop, I can see the trouble file?

The code:

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}},lastwritetime,length,fullname | export-csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv" -notypeinformation
```

aaaa

Comment: you shouldn't run this in a  single pipeline, any issues will cause the entire operation to stop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list progress, you need to know where your process will end, so you need to list all the files BEFORE you start operating on them.

```
Write-Host "Listing Files..." -Fore Yellow
$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File
$CurrentFile = 0 ; $TotalFiles = $AllFiles.Count

Write-Host "Hashing Files..." -Fore Yellow
$AllHashes = foreach ($File in $AllFiles){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Hashing Files" -Status "$($CurrentFile)/$($TotalFiles) $($File.FullName)" -PercentComplete (($CurrentFile++/$TotalFiles)*100)

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        File = $File.FullName
        Hash = (Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $File.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash
        LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
        Size = $File.Length
    }
}

$AllHashes | Export-Csv "File.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This will give you a nice header with a progress bar, which looks like this:

ISE:

[image]

Normal Shell:

[image]

Comment: this is very nice, thank you! two question please (1) how to run this by default in the CWD, and (2) format so the size will not be rounded (I use for fingerprint, needs exact): `"ABAA883BE66B93A4D9896CA3940B42D7","2017.11.20. 13:06:46","24363730","C:\.....`

Comment: to do the **CWD by default**, 2nd line changed to: `$AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File`

Comment: thank you. i like your code a lot. however, when i am trying out on 4 TB , 1 million files, it gets stuck on "Listing files..." (no progress bar yet). the drive contains one or more problem files, and I am trying to identify which one are those. any tweak so the Listing files would print out on the display so i assume the last line it stops is the problem file?

Comment: @HakariDo if you want a 'x% complete' bar you need to know what '100%' is, so it needs to complete the file listing first, it will take a long time but the overall runtime will not be impacted a huge amount.

Comment: your code works nicely in small (100 GB, 10K files), but when I try on 5TB, 1million files it crashes. I start the code,  it says `Listing Files...`, but then after about 5-10 minutes the code disappears and the powershell ISE displays one line only: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>`. any  thoughts? thank you.

Comment: You'll run out out memory counting files like that. I just counted under 200K files and the process grabbed over 600MB of RAM. A crude alternative would be  `$TotalFiles = 0; Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % { $TotalFiles +=1 }`

Comment: Accumulating all the hashes in a variable is also going to eat up a lot of memory. In addition, you won't see anything in the CSV file until all the hashing is done. This is a job where using the pipeline really makes a lot of sense.