# How to ignore unhashable (corrupt) files when doing md5 fingerprint?

Tags: windows, powershell

The code below makes an md5 and other metadata fingerprint, but crashes on files with unknown corruption (e.g., files, that can be copied, mostly even opened, but that can not be hashed or zipped up [to disguise their corruption]).

Question: How one makes this code to skip or ignore any problem files and just do the rest? Imagine 1 million files on 8 TB.

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | 
  Select-object @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName |
  Select-object -expandproperty Hash}},lastwritetime,length,fullname |
  Export-csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: What breaks? Does `Get-FileHash -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` help?

Comment: thanks. i have not tired. where to insert in the code?

Comment: `Select-object @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName |`

Comment: seems to work, i am testing on a larger set. any way to log the error files' full path and name into a .txt file, while the code is doing meantime the md5 hash on the rest?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to use a `foreach-object` section and wrap some error control around `get-FileHash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$errLogPath = "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file_ERROR.csv"

Get-childitem -recurse -file | 
  foreach-object {

    $file = $_

    try {
        $hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -path $file.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
        $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $hash.Hash -PassThru
    } catch {
        $file | 
            add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Exception -Value $_.Exception.Message -PassThru |
            Select-Object -Property Name, FullName, Exception |
            Export-Csv -Path $errLogPath -append -notypeinformation
    }
  } | 
  select-object -Property Hash, LastWriteTime, Length, FullName |
  Export-csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Each file is processed through the `foreach-object` cmdlet. A `try...catch` is used to capture exceptions, and an `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter is added to `get-FileHash` to ensure Terminating errors are raised and will trigger the catch.

If an error is caught, the file name, path and exception message are output to a CSV file.

EDIT: Adding in the progress bar

```
$logPath = "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv"
$errLogPath = "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file_ERROR.csv"

write-host "Counting files ..."

$maxFileCount = 0; get-childItem -recurse -file | % { $maxFileCount +=1 }

write-host "Hashing files ..."

$currFileCount = 0
Get-childitem -recurse -file | 
  foreach-object {

    $file = $_

    Write-Progress -Activity "Hashing Files" -Status ( "{0}/{1} - {2}" -f $currFileCount, $maxFileCount, $File.FullName ) -PercentComplete (($currFileCount++)/$maxFileCount*100)

    try {
        $hash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -path $file.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
        $file | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hash -Value $hash.Hash -PassThru
    } catch {
        $file | 
            add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Exception -Value $_.Exception.Message -PassThru |
            Select-Object -Property Name, FullName, Exception |
            Export-Csv -Path $errLogPath -append -notypeinformation
    }


  } | 
  select-object -Property Hash, LastWriteTime, Length, FullName |
  Export-csv -Path $logPath -notypeinformation
```

Comment: this seems to work so far the best, thank you. is there a easy and un-intrusive way to add a progress monitor like `Write-Host `, something like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415133](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415133)? the reason as running on 8TB 2 million files, it would be **very** good to confirm it does the right stuff during the 1-2 day wait period.